# How to disallow duplicate rows to be saved when using the primeng p-table element

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-table

As shown below when editing a row in a primeng p-table element the edit allows for duplicate rows to be saved.

demo.component.html

```
<p-table [value]="blockOutRows" dataKey="id" [columns]="blockOutCols" editMode="row" [reorderableColumns]="true">
    
    ...

    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-editing="editing" let-index="rowIndex">
        <tr [pEditableRow]="rowData" pEditing="editing">
            <td>
                
                ...

            </td>

            <td>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">

                        <span class="p-float-label" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <p-calendar id="editStartTime" name="editStartTime" appendTo="body" [timeOnly]="true" [showSeconds]="false"
                                [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="rowData.startTime" icon="pi pi-clock" dataType="string"
                                [required]="isRequired">
                            </p-calendar>
                            <label>Start Time</label>
                        </span>

                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData.startTime}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>

            // EndTime column removed as stackoverflow was complaining about me having too much code in my question & not enough content. 

            <td>
                <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center gap-2 inline-item">
                    <button *ngIf="!editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pInitEditableRow icon="pi pi-pencil" (click)="onRowEditInit(rowData)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text"></button>
                    <button *ngIf="editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pSaveEditableRow icon="pi pi-check" (click)="onRowEditSave(rowData)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-success mr-2"></button>
                    <button *ngIf="editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" (click)="onRowEditCancel(rowData, index)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-danger"></button>
                </div>
                <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-trash" class="p-button-rounded"
                    (click)="deleteBlockOutDiary(rowData)" [disabled]="false"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>

</p-table>

...
```

demo.component.ts

```
...

clinicDiaryBlockOut!: ClinicianDiaryBlockOut;
clonedBlockOutRows: { [s: string]: ClinicianDiaryBlockOutRow } = {};

blockOutRows: Array<ClinicianDiaryBlockOutRow> = new Array<ClinicianDiaryBlockOutRow>();

...
```

The issue is here, as the onRowEditSave accepts duplicate startTime & endTime. How do I only allow the record to be saved if the startTime & endTime does not exist.

```
onRowEditSave(row: ClinicianDiaryBlockOutRow) {
  let found = false;

  this.blockOutRows.forEach(function(value) {
    if (row.startTime === value.startTime && row.stopTime === value.stopTime) {
      found = true;
      return;
    }
  });

  if (found) {
    this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Please choose a different start & end time, as the start & end time chosen already exists!' });
  } else {
    if (row.startTime !== "" && row.stopTime !== "") {
      delete this.clonedBlockOutRows[row.id as string];
      this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Block Out time updated' });
    } else {
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Invalid Block Out time' });
    }
  }
}
```

As seen in the image below the edit allows duplicate rows to be saved:
[image]